# APACHE REDIRECT TO TOMCAT USING MOD_PROXY

Tags: mod-proxy

I am trying to implement a redirect for apache2 t tomcat.I would like to have a url like this: `share.com` to open to alfresco login page, but currently I have to use the url like this:

```
share.com/share/  .
```

I have done research and what I achieved was removing the 8080 port from the url:

```
share.com:8080/share/
```

only remains the /share; How can I remove the /share part too?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do can be achieved with a ProxyPass. The below entry will cause everything to go to Tomcat/share.

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/share
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/share
```

For the above to work, mod_proxy_http will need to be installed and loaded. This would either be done with a dynamic load config line in the conf file:

```
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Or compiled into Apache:

```
./httpd -l | grep proxy
mod_proxy.c
mod_proxy_connect.c
mod_proxy_ftp.c
mod_proxy_http.c
mod_proxy_scgi.c
mod_proxy_ajp.c
mod_proxy_balancer.c
```